# Why ASP.Net HtmlEditorExtender dropping space after postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm using asp.net htmlEditorExtender, when i copy data from word and paste it into editor and after clicked on button space will automatically drops, why is this happening?

I was using ajax control toolkit version 16.1 now i updated it to 18.1 but  getting same problem.

Here is my code

```
           <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRichTextEditor" runat="server" Text="TextEditor" CssClass="control-label col-md-3"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="eBody" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <cc1:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExteBody" runat="server" TargetControlID="eBody" EnableSanitization="false" DisplaySourceTab="false">
                            <Toolbar>
                                <cc1:Undo />
                                <cc1:Redo />
                                <cc1:Copy />
                                <cc1:Paste />
                                <cc1:Bold />
                                <cc1:Cut />
                                <cc1:Italic />
                                <cc1:Underline />
                                <cc1:FontSizeSelector />
                                <cc1:FontNameSelector />
                                <cc1:UnLink />
                            </Toolbar>
                        </cc1:HtmlEditorExtender>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-3">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by **Updating Ajax control tool kit to latest version(18.1)** and added **TextMode="Multiline"** in textbox.

Here is My Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="eBody" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="250px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```